# Connecting to Sql Server with Python 3 in Windows

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database-connection, python-module

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how I can connect to MS SQL Server with Python? What I want to do is read a text file, extract some values and then insert the values from the text file into a table in my Sql Server database. I am using Python 3.1.3, and it seems some of the modules I have come across in research online are not included in the library. Am I missing something? Is there a good 3rd party module I should know about. Any help would be greatly appreciated.I am using Windows. thanks

Comment: Specify from which platform do you want to connect to MS SQL Server, I think that there is no native Python-SQL Server connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch more [SQL Server libraries listed on the Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server). At least [mxODBC](http://www.egenix.com/) is fully ready for Python 3.1, but I haven't used it so I can't comment on its appropriateness...

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pymssql](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/wiki/Documentation) module. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/wiki/Compilation) you can find installation instructions

Comment: It looks like this module does not work with versions of python after 2.6 so far.

Comment: Yes: "there is work in progress to support Python 3.0 and 3.1". I've found one more connector: [link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC), [how-to](http://www.time-travellers.org/shane/howtos/MS-SQL-Express-Python-HOWTO.html), [one more link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server)

Comment: Here is [using mssql from within python 2.5](http://ramblings.timgolden.me.uk/2007/09/26/using-mssql-from-within-python-25/), but the article has been written in 2007, that's why may be Python 3 support

Answer (score 1):

I found a module called CEODBC that I was able to use with Python 3 after doing some research. It looks like they will also be releasing a Python3 compatible version of PYODBC soon. Thanks for all your help.