# Which Microsoft SQL library should I download

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting to Sql Server with Python 3 in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154069/connecting-to-sql-server-with-python-3-in-windows)

I want to connect sql server with python... but I don't know which one download...

Here the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=sql%20server%20service%20pack)

Answer (score 1):

there are various ways to connect python to SQL Server

look here

http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server

and if there's something you don't understand, specify it

Answer (score 0):

If you want a free version of SQL Server, go for Express edition.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

There's restrictions to the free version, but I do not recall restrictions on what languages to access the server from.